# Determinant obtained from a function on a semi-lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, order-theory

I've seen on the site and elsewhere calculations of determinants of the form $\det (\min(i,j))$ and $\det(\gcd(i,j))$.

There is a general formula in the following case: $\mathcal{O}$ is a finite partially-ordered set which is a lower [semilattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice), $a\colon \mathcal{O} \to R$ is a function from $\mathcal{O}$ to a commutative ring $R$.

Problem: calculate the determinant
$$\det(a_{\inf(i,j)})_{i,j\in \mathcal{O}}$$

Note: the determinants of form $\det(a_{\min(i,j)})_{1\le i,j \le n}$ were calculated by George Boole (an [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Det%5B%20Table%5B%20a%5BMin%5Bi%2Cj%5D%5D%2C%20%7Bi%2C1%2C5%7D%2C%20%7Bj%2C1%2C5%7D%5D%20%5D) for $n=5$). His idea works in the general case.

The question is left  for further [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) purposes. Thank you for your interest!

$\bf{Added:}$ @amrsa: just pointed out that this setup works for any set $\mathcal{O}$ with a binary operation. We have a similarity with [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), or group determinants. In those cases we have some interesting formulas too.

$\bf{Added:}$

I will add a solution to the problem.

Let $\mathcal{O}$ a partially ordered set, $R$ an abelian group. Given a function $a\colon \mathcal{O}\to R$ there exists a (unique) function $b\colon \mathcal{O}\to R$ such that
$$a(i) = \sum_{k\le i} b(k)$$

(see [Mobius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula))

The reason for the existence is the following: the linea map $b\mapsto a$  from $R^{\mathcal{O}}$ to itself is of the form $I + N$ where $N$ is a lower triangular matrix, so nilpotent. This implies $I+N$ is invertible, with the inverse given by a Neumann series $I-N + N^2 - \cdots$. So the Mobius function appears as the entries in this inverse matrix.

Now, consider the lower triangular matrix $(\delta_{i \ge k})_{i,k \in \mathcal{O}}$.
We have
$$a_i = \sum_{k \le i} b_i = \sum_k \delta_{i \le k} b_k$$

Now assume that $\mathcal{O}$ is also a lower-lattice, that is, every two elements $i$, $j$ have an infimum $\inf(i,j)$. We have

$$a_{\inf(i,j)} = \sum_{k \le \inf(i,j)} b_k = \sum_{k \le i \textrm{ and }  k\le j} b_k = \sum \delta_{i\ge k} \cdot b_k \cdot \delta_{j\ge k}$$

We have gotten an Choleski decomposition of the symmetric matrix $A$. We conclude that
$$\det A = \prod_{k \in \mathcal{O}} b_i$$

Note: the matrix $(\delta_{ik}) = (\delta_{i\ge k})$ is lower triangular unipotent since the nonzero entries are in the region $i \ge k$. Its transpose is upper triangular. This lower ( upper) thing works  well for determinants.

Comment: That seems exactly the same as making a matrix as the image by the map $a$ in the ring of the multiplication table of some binary operation on the original algebra, be it a semi-lattice or other (with a binary operation, of course); and then calculate the determinant. It maybe that the semi-lattice case is more interesting for some reason...

Comment: @amrsa: the semilattice is so we have $\inf(i,j)$ for all $i,j \in \mathcal{O}$. The fact is the determinant has a certain structure. It is not hard to see what happens when $\mathcal{O} = \{1,2,\ldots n\}$.  I think I understand what you mean by the operation, neat idea! Like  circular determinants, or the group determinant.  Great comment, thanks!

Comment: I didn't even know the concept of group determinant was studied and interesting. So I also learn something from this, thanks! Perhaps the question is more interesting  than it occurred to me in the beginning.

Comment: @amrsa: Glad it stirred your interest!